# C++ code to test another .cpp if its possible to compile it

Tags: c++, qt, testing, assert

I would like to ask if there is any good tool for create a code for testing another code if its possible to compile it without errors.

I am coding app in C++ and Qt for testing another codes.

Have you got any recomendation ? I was thinking if it would be possible to use QProcess with assert() somehow. But I want to know more possibilities.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: a compiler? The question is not quite clear. If I want to know if something compiles I ask my compiler

Comment: I am coding app (c++ and Qt) which should test another .cpp does if its possible to compile them.

Comment: Take a look to Google Test or even the QTest part in Qt

Comment: ok, the easiest is to invoke your compiler and check its output, note that "does it compile" and "run some test" are not the same, I also suspect you rather want the latter

Comment: Thank you both of you ! I will look on all of these 3 ways and decide which will be best for me. You have helped me a lot now.

Comment: If you use CMake you can use `try_compile` command.

Comment: you could still try to clarify the quesiton so someone could write an answer

Answer (score 0):

Usually to test if a cpp file compiles is just a compiler call. This is usually not really an issue.

But in C++ it is very easy to get circular headers or headers with missing includes, missing inline modifiers...

To test if all my headers do not depent on some include order / compile on their own, I wrote a small NUnit test (in C#), which takes all my headers in my project and creates two cpp files with this header included. These cpp files are then compiled to a single file.

I do this test with gcc, clang and msvc. It is not a garantee that all headers are fine because some errors can occure in template instantiation, but it improves header quality a lot.